# Writing image pixel data to printer code

Tags: python, performance, strings, image, lookup

I've been trying to take image pixel data and write it out into printer code and my results are rather slow.

Here is a simplified version of what I have so far (image is a PIL Image object of 1200 x 1800 pixels):

```
# ~36 seconds on beaglebone
f.write(pclhead)
pix = image.getdata()
for y in xrange(1800):
  row = '\xff'*72
  ### vvv slow code vvv ###
  for x in xrange(1200):
    (r,g,b) = pix[y*1200+x]
    row += chr(g)+chr(b)+chr(r)
  ### ^^^ slow code ^^^ ###
  row += '\xff'*72
  f.write(row)
f.write(pclfoot)
```

I know the loop can be optimized way better, but how?

My code is running on a **beaglebone** so speed is slower than you'd expect, but composing the complex images takes about 5 seconds. I wouldn't expect my printer code function (which just reorders the data) to take much longer than about 2 or 3 seconds. My first attempt (with `getpixel`) took 90 seconds. Now I have it down to **36 seconds**.  Surely I can make this quite a bit faster yet.

For comparison, just so we can all see where the hold up is, this code runs in **0.1 secs** (but, of course, is lacking the important data):

```
# ~0.1 seconds on beaglebone
f.write(pclhead)
pix = image.getdata()
for y in xrange(1800):
  row = '\xff'*72
  ### vvv substituted vvv ###
  row += '\xff'*3600
  ### ^^^ substituted ^^^ ###
  row += '\xff'*72
  f.write(row)
f.write(pclfoot)
```

I guess a simplified version of this problem is to rewrite something like the following:

```
[ (1,2,3), (1,2,3) ... 1200 times ]
```

into

```
[ 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, etc... ]
```

but as a string

```
"\x02\x03\x01\x02\x03\x01 ... "
```

Comment: instead of all that string manipulation why not just write it out.

Comment: @cmd, write what out? did you notice the byte order has changed?

Comment: is `f` just a simple file object? What do we know about how it buffers writes?

Comment: @kojiro, f.write() can be slow, i know, but i just want to optimize the way the loop handles the data

Comment: That is only fair if your *36 seconds* doesn't include the `f.write`. :P

Comment: In the code that runs in 0.1 seconds, the compiler is probably using Constant Propagation to optimize the loop. It can't do that with your actual code because the data changes. Hm... didn't realize this was so old, but I'll leave my comment around for others anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the code I finally arrived at. Not only is it way faster (less than 1 second!), but it still maintains good legibility and doesn't rely on additional libraries.

This assumes the image format is raw 'RGB' as was the case in the original scenario. Instead of image.getdata() which returns a set of tuples, I am now using image.getstring() which doesn't need as much coercsion to manipulate its data. Also, by preallocating rpix as a bytearray of known size, you save a lot of memory block copying.

```
# <1 second on beaglebone
f.write(pclhead)

mgn = '\xff'*72
pix = image.getstring()
rpix = bytearray(len(pix))
rpix[0::3] = pix[1::3]
rpix[1::3] = pix[2::3]
rpix[2::3] = pix[0::3]

offs = 0
for y in xrange(1800):
  f.write(mgn)
  f.write(str(rpix[offs:offs+3600]))
  f.write(mgn)
  offs += 3600
f.write(pclfoot)
```

Answer (score 6):

Start with storing the `'\xff' * 72` string as a constant; Python strings are immutable, recreating that string each time is not necessary.

Next, use a list to collect all strings, then join at the end; this is cheaper than constant string concatenation.

Last, avoid attribute lookups in critical sections; assign any attribute lookups done more than once to a local name:

```
from operator import itemgetter

bgr = itemgetter(1,2,0)

pix = image.getdata()
rowstart = '\xff' * 72
f_write = f.write
empty_join = ''.join
for y in xrange(1800):
    row = [rowstart]
    r_extend = row.extend
    for x in xrange(1200):
        r_extend(map(chr, bgr(pix[y*1200+x])))
    r.append(rowstart)

    f_write(empty_join(row))
```

You can experiment with joining the whole row (including `rowstart`) or writing out `rowstart` values separately; the following version might be faster still depending on write speed versus list concatenation speed:

```
for y in xrange(1800):
    f_write(rowstart)
    row = []
    r_extend = row.extend
    for x in xrange(1200):
        r_extend(map(chr, bgr(pix[y*1200+x])))
    f_write(empty_join(row))
    f_write(rowstart)
```

Comment: I tried your code from above and it takes 58 seconds, so actually slower than my code :(

Comment: Could you optimize this further by a single loop over `range(0, 1800*1200+1, 1200)` inserting `'\xff'*144` every 1200 iterations?

Comment: (Perhaps even a direct operation on such a slice of `pix` will work if you can solve the byte-swapping problem.)

Comment: What if, instead of maintaining a list of strings and doing `chr` on an integer, you just use a `bytearray`?

Answer (score 4):

First Profile your code to determine what is your bottleneck.

But generally speaking, there are scopes of improvement

1. Do not generate the strings of HIGH Values inside the Loop
2. Use Generators
3. Process a 1D List as a 1D list rather than Indexing with two loops

Sample Code

```
f.write(pclhead)
pix = image.getdata()
HIGH_VALUES = '\xff'*72
#pix_it = (''.join(map(chr, reversed(e))) for e in pix)

pix_it = (chr(b)+chr(g)+chr(r) for r,g,b in pix)
while True:
    data = ''.join(islice(pix_it, 1200))
    if not data: break
    f.write(HIGH_VALUES)
    f.write(data)
    f.write(HIGH_VALUES)
```

Comment: this took 30 seconds. marginally faster but not significant.

Comment: @Octopus: Profile Your Code and see where the bottleneck is. The above code for me took only 3 secs. Off-course, the data was randomly generated rather than reading from a file through PIL.

Comment: I said my times are coming from a beaglebone so they are expectedly slower, but compare your time to mine

Answer (score 3):

Can you use `numpy`? If you provide a test image it would help (I know most of this answer works, but unsure about `tofile` doing the right thing here)

```
import numpy
f.write(pclhead)
pix = numpy.array(image).astype(numpy.uint8) #Array shape is (x, y, 3)
pix[:,:,[0,1,2]] = pix[:,:,[1,2,0]] #Swap rgb values to gbr, this is a 'view' so is fast
to_insert = numpy.ones((72, pix.shape[1], 3)).astype(numpy.uint8) * 255
pix = numpy.concatenate((to_insert, pix, to_insert), axis=0).astype(numpy.uint8)
pix.tofile(f)
f.write(pclfoot)
```

Comment: The line that swaps rgb values gives me an error.

Comment: @Octopus Can you tell me what `pix.shape` is immediately before that line? The swap works fine on my machine with a small image loaded through PIL.

Comment: My mistake, i made an error above that. This is faster and has potential, but my pcl file is now 56MB instead of 7MB. ~18 secs

Comment: @Octupus That's a shame. Not sure why? Maybe the concatenation, let me have a look.

Comment: @Octupus I'm now ensuring the dtypes for the "ones" and the result of the concatenation are `uint8`. The data type may have been mangled in there somewhere in the version you tested.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can save even more time by keeping to iterables of integers as long as possible, and switching to `bytearray` at the last possible moment. Also, as tradeoffs usually go, you can save time by keeping more in RAM and saving it all for one final `.write`. Exactly how well that works will depend on buffering.

```
from itertools import chain, imap, izip_longest
from operator import itemgetter

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    """Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks
    Copied directly from http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes
    """
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

pix = chain.from_iterable(imap(itemgetter(1, 2, 0), image.getdata()))
rows = grouper(pix, 3600)
# Rows is an iterable of iterables of integers in the range 0-255.

space = bytearray([255] * 72)
img = space + (2 * space).join(map(bytearray, rows)) + space
# You'll need at least ~6.4M in RAM, but the BeagleBone has 256! :)
f.write(img)
```

Comment: This works and is the fastest yet at ~13 secs